# Let a Package use the ServiceProvider of a "master"package in Laravel

Tags: laravel, package

I want to develop some packages for Laravel. So I want to create a "master" package fitting the Laravel-package-development guidelines as written on [Laravel.com](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/packages). Then I want to extend this package with other packages (or let other developers extend it).

Because of this, I want to make it as easy as possible for me/them. So I am looking for a way to register these sub-packages without the need of registering them in the config/app.php.

It would be great if these sub-packages could be registered and activated through the master-package, which is correctly registered via ServiceProvider, ClassAlias and Facade. Or is there a way to register them automatically in config/app.php?

I found a package on GitHub [caffeinated/modules](https://github.com/caffeinated/modules), which provides something like this, but there it's not possible to install and update new packages via composer.

It would be great, if one of you could help me with this problem, because I want to make it as easy as possible to extend the master-package.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need caffeinated/modules, Laravel supports registering modules with all of their components out of the box, so this package is unnecessary.

What I usually do for my modules is - I have a main provider that registers the other providers of the other modules:

```
class MainModuleServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->register( FirstModuleServiceProvider::class );
        $this->app->register( SecondModuleServiceProvider::class );
    }
}
```

And in each of these providers I register providers for the module views, routes, etc.:

```
class FirstModuleServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->register( RouteServiceProvider::class );
        $this->app->register( ViewServiceProvider::class );
    }
}
```

In these providers I load the views, routes and publish the migrations as described in the Laravel doc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will test it later.